# paths are homologous , but are not freely homotopic

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, complex-integration

Given a pair of closed paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$ . $\alpha(t)=2ie^{it/2}$ for $0\leq t\leq4\pi$, and  $\beta=\beta_1+\beta_2$ with $\beta_1(t)=-1+e^{it}$ and $\beta_2(t)=  1-e^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq2\pi$,

(1)  $\gamma=\beta_2+\beta_1-\beta_2-\beta_1, A=\Bbb C \setminus \{-1,  1\}$ . How to show that $\gamma$ is not contractible in $A$?

(2) $B=\Bbb C \setminus \{-1/2,  1/2\}$. Decide whther $\alpha$ and $\beta$  are freely homotopic in $B$?

A free homotopy between two closed paths $ \lambda,\mu:[a,b]⟶U $  is a continuos function $H:[a,b]×[0,1]⟶U$, such that $H(t,0)=\lambda(t), H(t,1)=\mu(t) $ and $H(a,s)=H(b,s),∀t∈[a,b],∀s∈[0,1]$.

$\gamma$ is contractible in $A$ means $\gamma$ is freely homotopic in $A$ to a constant path.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are homologous in $U$ if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have same winding numbers around every point in  $\Bbb C\setminus U$

---

Source: An introduction to complex function theory, Bruce P. Palka  P204, P213

It is obvious that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are homologous in $B$($\alpha$ and $\beta$ have same winding numbers around  $-1/2, 1/2$), I think  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not freely homotopic in $A$. But how to prove this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the role of $B$? Why don't you work with only one of $A$ or $B$ in both parts of the question?

Comment: You should also add Palka's definition of homologous.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks!   Two problems are independent. definition of homologous be added

Comment: Why should there be any difference between regions $A$ and $B$? For the first question, the usual explanation involves the fundamental group. Perhaps you should change your mind about about whether $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are freely homotopic (whether in $A$ or in $B$ is inconsequential).

Comment: @TedShifrin    Thanks!  the textbook said (1) is non-trivial, but there is no clue

Comment: I don't think you are expected to prove it with just the tools in a complex variables book/course. The point is that the fundamental group of the doubly-punctured plane is the free product of $\Bbb Z$ with itself, and you are looking at the element $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, where $a$ and $b$ generate the respective factors. When you abelianize (which is what looking at "homologous" does), this becomes trivial, but it is most definitely a non-trivial element; one way to see this is to look at the universal covering space. So, time for a first course in algebraic topology.

Comment: @TedShifrin  What about (2)? Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$   freely homotopic in $B$? 
 All I could say is--thanks

Comment: They are freely homotopic in $A$ and in $B$, and there's absolutely no difference in the two regions. I don't know what Palka was thinking about here. Perhaps he was thinking of using the centers of the circle for his free homotopy and then you'd have to rethink it when it's not the centers.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Does $H(t,s)=(1-s)\alpha(t)+ s\beta(t)$ furnish a  free homotopy form $\alpha$ to  $\beta$ ? Thanks a million

Comment: I think so. You have to define $\beta$, of course, and what will its domain be? This should explain why Palka chose the bizarre parametrization of the circle $\alpha$.